# Generate a mantis's head (symmetrical triangle)

Tags: code-golf, array, open-ended-function

Given guaranteed strictly positive **integers \$w\$ and \$n\$**, output

- An **equilateral triangle array** with **side length \$w\$**, filled with two distinct, consistent values. I'll call these `0` and `1` but they do not have to be equal to `0` and `1`.
- The **number of `1`s** inside this array **must be equal to \$n\$**.
- The output triangle **must be symmetrical**, meaning that it is the same when flipped horizontally or diagonally (**your choice**).
- An equilateral triangle array can be an array with \$w\$ elements where for \$1\$ to \$w\$ (inclusive), there is a sub-array with that number of elements inside of \$w\$ (for example, but it may be outputted via ascii-art, see below).

(\$n\$ values are guaranteed to fit in the triangle)

### Examples

```
w=3, n=1
  1
 0 0
0 0 0

w=3, n=2
  0
 1 1
0 0 0

w=3, n=3
  1
 1 1
0 0 0

w=3, n=4
  0
 1 1
1 0 1

w=3, n=5
  0
 1 1
1 1 1

w=3, n=6
  1
 1 1
1 1 1
```

### Valid Output Format List

In this case the distinct values are `1` and `0`.
Possible output triangles (all considered equivalent) with `1`s at their corners and center and a width of 4 are:

```
   1
  0 0
 0 1 0
1 0 0 1
```

```
1
00
010
1001
```

```
[[1],[0,0],[0,1,0],[1,0,0,1]]
```

```
1 0 0 1
 0 1 0
  0 0
   1
```

```
[[1],[0,0],[0,1,0],[1,0,0,1]]
```

```
1
0
00
11
00
0
1
```

```
1
 0
0 0
 1 1
0 0
 0
1
```

---

[here is a test case validator in Jq](https://jqplay.org/s/fuamafVDxH), takes `{"w": w, "n": n, "a": result you wish to check}` (in the JSON array format like `[[1],[0,0],[0,1,0],[1,0,0,1]]`)

Comment: [Sandboxed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/22341/3)

Comment: For w=3, n=1; Why output is 1;0,0;0,0,0 instead of 0;0,0;0,1,0?

Comment: @tsh Both are valid, I guess the former was just easier to type :P

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
RØ.ṗŒpFS=ɗƇUƑƇḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//UsOYLuG5l8WScEZTPcmXxodVxpHGh@G4ov///zP/NA)

-1 byte thanks to caird coinheringaahing

```
RØ.ṗŒpFS=ɗƇUƑƇḢ  Main Link; accepts w as the left argument and n as the right argument
R                Range; [1, 2, ..., w]
 Ø.ṗ             [0, 1] ~ cartesian power ~ ^
    Œp           Cartesian Product of ^'s items - this gets all valid triangles of the right size
      ---ɗƇ      Keep elements where
       S         the sum of
      F          the triangle flattened
        =        equals (right argument)
             Ƈ   Keep elements where
            Ƒ    the element is the same when
           U     each sub-list is reversed
              Ḣ  Get the first such triangle
```

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//UsOYLuG5l8WScEZTPcmXxodVxpHGh@G4ov///zP/NA)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing oh yeah it's not a 0,2 chain so I don't need to specify right argument. i'm dumb lol

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 54 bytes

A much shorter approach. I think this is equivalent to [@ovs' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226109/58563).

Expects `(n)(w)`. Returns a list of lists, from bottom to top.

```javascript
n=>g=w=>w?[Array(w).fill(n<w?0:(n-=w,1)),...g(w-1)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BbsIwFET3nGKW/zeOS2i7ITiIRU8RZWEZO6Wy7MihtRDi7KnJrts3b2a@9a@eTbpM1zrEs12cWoLqRpVVl4/9KSV9o8zSXbyncMjH7Z5CrbJomIWUcqRcNzzs@2Fpe@wE3gTeBT4wSBfTpzZflKE63DdAARSg0LQIOChkvKCkFRrGK3aFVhWvJpDsXExHgct7uyITwxy9lT6OVGLxdKTz@koskz3/GEs0CRh@/k1l1vDafGz@dwt88PIH)

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>88</s>  85 bytes

This one inserts \$1\$'s as soon as it can.

Expects `(n)(w)`. Returns a list of lists, from bottom to top.

```javascript
n=>g=w=>w?[(h=q=>k--?k--?[q=n>1?--n/n--:0,...h(),q]:[n&&n/n--]:[])(k=w),...g(w-1)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY27bsMwDEX3fMWdArKWlDptl7iUp36F4cFQ/GhjyK@0Gop8uyt760CAOPdc8qv6qRY3f4537YdrvTayerGtBLEhL6iTSexN63ybYhJv01xrf/JaX56VMaYjVlN5KfzxuNO4lkw3CbylLQWd8sbWrMBZ4UXhVeENpWmG@aNyHQWIxe8BiIA8BGkGj3dBwBNimiBlnHCONEl4N4G5XqLZkGcKnO3IDX4Z@tr0Q0sxVptjmr66E5u5vn67mmhUcLz9G@NZx3vzcfjfjfDB6x8)

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 20 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ò1 Ô®>V?Zî0:(VµZ,Zî1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8jEg1K4%2bVj9a7jA6KFa1Wixa7jE&footer=bV9xIHFTfSAg%2byBxUg&input=Mwo0)

- we start from the biggest row,
  if `n` is not smaller than its length we fill the row with 1s
- we can always put the rest of 1s on the next lines.
- filling entire rows gives a specular triangle.

  ```
  - input: U=w , V=n
  ò1 Ô   - range[1..w] reversed
  ®      - map to Z=>
  >V?    - if Z>n
  Zî0     * string of Z 0s
  :(     - else
  VµZ,    * n-=Z and..
  Zî1     * string of Z 1s
  ```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 47 bytes

Returns a nested list of booleans.

```python
f=lambda w,n:w*[1]and[[x:=n>=w]*w]+f(w-1,n-w*x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczLDoIwEIXhPU8xG9ILFFLcGBJ8EcICpSgGp6RWBje@euWynfP9M339w@LpPLkQ@mpsX9euBUqxJFnrpsWurpeywktFjaQm6TkpnaIiuYhAUMEp6q0DhAHBtXg3nKT6UZ4XiRZlBODM@zP6Fa5limK9bN5Z2ot93BjA5Ab0nAHLnnZAzuKOxfOO551aEtnNoDeOF3I0yI9YKC22r0cuwh8)

Comment: I have limited python experience... and would have assumed that only the right hand side of the `and` is ever returned.  How does `w*[1]` come into play?

Comment: @Jonah As long as `w` is positive `w*[1]` is some non-empty list, which is always truthy, and the right hand side is returned. But as soon as `w` reaches zero this evaluates to the empty list (falsy) and serves as the base case of the recursion. (I could've used any other value instead of the `1`)

Comment: Thanks.  Empty list = falsy is the piece I was missing... coming from ruby.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>20</s> 12 bytes

Based on the observation that all outputs can be created by having each row as all 1's or all 0's. Check out [AZTECCO's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226105/64121), which got there an hour earlier.

```
1ÝIã.ΔƶOQ}ā×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9vc2FiaWX//zHDnUnDoy7OlMa2T1F9xIHDl/99zrVTw7DDvX0uY/8zCjU)

```python
1Ý            # push the range [0..1] == [0, 1]
  Iã          # raise this to the first input (w) cartesian power
              # this yields all w-tuples of 1's and 0's
    .Δ   }    # find the first that satisfies:
      ƶ       #   each value multiplied by its 1-based index
       O      #   take the sum of that
        Q     #   is equal to the second input (n)
          ā   # push the range [1..len(value)] == [1..w]
           ×  # repeat each digit in the select tuple that number of times
```

---

Alternative 12 byters (Both find a subset of `[1..w]` that sums to `n` and build the triangle from that):

```
L©æ.ΔOQ}®å®×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f59DKw8v0zk3xD6w9tO7wUiCe/v@/MZcpAA)

```
LDæIÅœÃнsåā×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9vc2FiaWX//0xEw6ZJw4XFk8OD0L1zw6XEgcOX//8zCjU)

Comment: Ehm.. Do you refer to my observation?

Comment: @AZTECCO I didn't read through your answer before, but it seems like you got there first (+1)

Comment: that's fine then. Thanks for giving me credits anyway!

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>48</s> <s>40</s> 28 bytes

```
ＮηＦ⮌…·¹Ｎ«Ｇ↘↖ιＩ¬‹ηι↓¿¬‹ηι≧⁻ιη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU7NCsIwGDuvT9HjN5iHIV62k@hlsA0Z@AB1fGsLtR39ExGfvW7uIphTEpKQUTA7GqZSavQcfB/uN7Qg8ppMxlIYMKJ1CI0eVXAy4sA0RygL@hvPF9AXyS5GPbnRUJ3NQw@SC1/Q6jq3OC1EFvTEnIfeeGjRORCLtzZrknUm4tZalZzoX4p2bD46J/m2C53UwX1H16/vlMo9OaRdVB8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes arguments in the order `n`, `w`. Explanation: Port of @AZTECCO's answer.

```
Ｎη
```

Input `n`.

```
Ｆ⮌…·¹Ｎ«
```

Count from `w` down to `1`.

```
Ｇ↘↖ιＩ¬‹ηι↓
```

Output a line of `1`s or `0`s depending on whether `n` is big enough.

```
¿¬‹ηι≧⁻ιη
```

Reduce `n` accordingly.

Previous 40 byte answer:

```
ＮθＦＮ⊞υ¹Ｅθ⭆Ｅ⌊⟦⊕ι⁻θι⟧‹⁺ιλ⊖θ∧›№υ¹λ⊟Ｅ⊕λ⊟υ‖Ｏ↘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5NC4JAEIbv/oo9zoAdIrrkKRJC6EPqGB3MRl1Yd3XdrZ@/jUrUwBzeZ154pmwKW5pChZDpzruTbx9kocckqowV8A8RRe6HBnwslnzPrdQOjkUHfSyujlM9hmmllq1v4Zbp0lJL2tETJMaCD34Y@xLvHA80DJArRjIWikFKv36PyGSrn7C3VDh@YGc8Gyf9XM/N7PvXfLnHeZLoQpWi0p1fZBWXN6l564usG4dJCOtouQqLl/oA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `w`.

```
ＦＮ⊞υ¹
```

Input `n` and make a list of that many `1`s.

```
Ｅθ
```

Start drawing a triangle of height `w`.

```
⭆Ｅ⌊⟦⊕ι⁻θι⟧
```

Draw the upper left half of the triangle.

```
‹⁺ιλ⊖θ
```

Calculate whether this square lies on the diagonal or not.

```
∧›№υ¹λ⊟Ｅ⊕λ⊟υ
```

If `n` is large enough to need both this square and its reflection, then reduce `n` accordingly and output a `1`, otherwise output a `0`. This always works because the very last square is on the diagonal.

```
‖Ｏ↘
```

Reflect to complete the triangle.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 62 bytes

```c
f(w,n,c){for(c=n>=w,w&&f(w-1,n-w*c);~w;putchar(w--?48+c:10));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5BDoIwEEXX7SmaJjSttAkIEmNFz0LGoF04GsB0QfDqderiLf7Lz58BdwdIadTRogWzjq9JQ4@XPtqoFGlXW3RxB8Z/o39/FngME1l3bY8lnOrKGL@l5xBQm5WzgIugJc9ZHsop9JUP586HsswFNsOAo5bFTRQ3aVW0Cg3V2f8Dky/MWsqsNr6lRtS8EXuiIVriQHQ/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ŒPS=¥ƇḢċ⁹xɗⱮ⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//xZJQUz3CpcaH4biixIvigbl4yZfisa7igbj///8z/zU)

A dyadic link taking `w` as its left argument and `n` as it’s right. Returns a list of lists of 0s and 1s. Based on the observation by @AZTECCO and @ovs that we can compose this solely of rows of 0s and 1s so be sure to upvote their answers too!

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 33 bytes

```
((]echo@#>:)]0>.<:@],~[-]*>:)/^:_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NTRiU5Mz8h2U7aw0Yw3s9GysHGJ16qJ1Y7WAAvpxVvH/NbnSgOqNgaQhmDQCk8Zg0gRMmoJJMyD5HwA)

A function whose output (rather than return value) prints what we want.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `r`, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
⅛ɾṘƛ¼:n≤:Sn*,[-⅛
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%E2%85%9B%C9%BE%E1%B9%98%C6%9B%C2%BC%3An%E2%89%A4%3ASn*%2C%5B-%E2%85%9B&inputs=5%0A3&header=&footer=)

```
⅛                # (Implicit input) Push to global array
 ɾṘ              # (Implicit input) range(1,n+1) reversed
   ƛ             # Foreach [n]
    ¼:           # Push from global array and duplicate [n,r,r]
      n≤         # Push n and check if r >= n [n,r,b]
        :Sn*,    # Duplicate, coerce to string (0 or 1), multi by n and output.
             [   # If ToS is truthy (r >= n) [n,r]
              -  # Subtract [r-n] (r flag reverses arguments)
               ⅛ # Push to global array.
```

Due to a bug with redefining the register inside a lambda, I'm forced to use the global array. It works well though, and I don't think it'd be any more golfable if the register worked properly.

Based on the insight that everything can be made of rows of 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 54 bytes

```r
function(w,n)for(i in w:1){show(1:i&(a=n>=i));n=n-i*a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP0@jXCdPMy2/SCNTITNPodzKULO6OCO/XMPQKlNNI9E2z842U1PTOs82TzdTK7H2f5qGsY6pJleahomOoeZ/AA)

Using `TRUE` and `FALSE` as the values.